# Capture a frame from a video (mpg, wmv, etc) at a specific time interval

Tags: c#, .net, video, image

Is there a way I can capture a single frame from a video file (mpg, wmv, flv, etc) at a specific point in the video (e.g. 5 seconds or the 25th frame)?  Then save it as an image?

[Edit]
Something link YouTube does.  That can't be all done manually? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) and [.net](http://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/) is your best choice

Comment: Neither of these are actually great options; .NET is entirely too generic to constitute any sort of reasonable answer.

Comment: Did you follow his link to see that he is refering to the FFMPEGdotnet project, the .net version of FFMPEG.

Comment: @kidjan .. I am using FFMPEG and .net in of my Video Hosting website to generate thumbnail. Please check the content before downvoting :)

Comment: Can you please write a more detailed answer?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/), because it'll let you do a lot of the work in managed code, which is quite a bit more friendly than doing it in native code.

You'll have to construct a filter graph to render the file you want, and you'll also need a file reader for the format of the file (i.e. if it's an MP4 file, you'll need an MP4 demux), and you'll need a decoder for the format of video (i.e. if it's H264, you'll need an H264 decoder filter).  I'd use Windows7 if possible, *it has much better media support*.

Your graph should look something like:

```
File Reader -> Video Decoder -> Sample Grabber -> Null Renderer
```

You'll construct your graph, and then call [IMediaSeeking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407023%28VS.85%29.aspx) to seek to the approximate time of the sample you want.  Then run the graph.  The decompressed frames will come in through a Sample Grabber callback interface.  You can check the timestamps and get the one that's closest to what you need.

From there, you can use .NET to save it as whatever image format you like (JPEG is probably best).